# Finding value of $\sin{\theta}$ from $\cos{\theta}$

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to solve a problem where I have the value of $\cos{\theta} = \dfrac{1}{3}$. I am struggling to find the value of $\sin{\theta}$ algebraically. Can someone provide some hint?

Comment: There are two possible answers. Use the identity $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An important identity in trigonometry is that $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta = 1$. One way to see that this is true, at least for $0^{\circ} \leq \theta \leq 90^{\circ}$, is to draw a right triangle. Choose one of the acute angles as $\theta$, and label the leg opposite that angle as $o$, the side next to that angle as $a$, and the hypotenuse as $h$. Then from the Pythagorean Theorem we have $o^2 + a^2 = h^2$, from which we conclude $\frac{o^2}{h^2} + \frac{a^2}{h^2} = \frac{h^2}{h^2}$, or $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta = 1$. Does that help?

Note that you will need to know what quadrant $\theta$ is in in order to know whether $\sin \theta$ should be positive or negative.

Answer (score 0):

$$ sin^2 \theta  = 1 - \cos^2 \theta = 1 - \frac 1 9 = \frac 8 9 $$
$$ \sin \theta = \sqrt \frac 8 9 = \frac { 2 \sqrt 2} {3} $$

Once you have one of the trigonometric functions you get all of them, $\tan \theta $ or $ \cos \theta $